# Getting keys of multidimensional array (of `[String: [String: String]]`)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with structure `[String: [String: String]]`. I am able to reach the `[String: String]` bit with a for loop, but I couldn't figure out how to access to the main keys (this bit `[String: [`).

```
let items = snapshot.value as! [String: [String: String]]

for item in items.values {
    if let from = item["from"] {
         self.users.append(from)   // this works
    }
}
```

How can I reach the main id of this node?

The node looks like this:

```
- table
     - "1"
        - "from": "AA"
        - "to": "BB"
     - "2"
        - "from": "AA"
        - "to": "BB"
```

I am trying to get `var array = ["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a Tuple will be clear try this :

```
let dict = ["1":["from":"aa","to":"bb"],"2":["from":"AA","to":"BB"]]

var array = [String]()
for (_ ,value) in dict{
    if let v = value["from"] {
        array.append(v)
    }
}
print(array)
```

### update:

```
let keys = dict.keys.flatMap({$0})

print(keys)
```

Comment: I am trying have array as `array = ["1","2"]` etc. "from" bit is working fine. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For arrays like that, where you have key->value pairs, you can access the key value as the element .0, and the value as element .1

Try this in a playground and see if it flies:

```
for firstLevel in tableArray {
    print(firstLevel.0)
    for innerLevel in firstLevel.1 {
        print(innerLevel.0)
        print(innerLevel.1)
    }
    print("\n")
}
```

Comment: This also works but other answer is more right. Thanks